# Does it make sense to typeset without inter-paragraph spacing?

Tags: luatex, memoir, parskip

I'm reading The Elements of Typographic Style, and note that there is no spacing between paragraphs except for the normal line spacing. In my opinion, this gives a professional impression, and I'd like the same for my thesis.

Would there be any issues typesetting a (Lua)LaTeX memoir document with several floats and equations with zero elastic inter-paragraph spacing? For instance, would it still be able to line up the bottom lines?

I'll add that I've read the memoir manual, and was not able to find any reference to the elastic part of paragraph spacing.

Comment: This depends on the size of the text area (height should be n * `\baselineskip` + `\topskip`) and the vertical spaces used, e.g., before and after sectioning headings and also on the size of such elements. I never use `\parskip` for my documents and do not have problems because of this.

Comment: I sometimes use vertical `\parskip` and `\flushbotttom` with multicolumn layout when register accuracy of columns on the same page and verso-recto-page-register-accuracy seem not of importance. The other way round not using a stretchable/shrinkable `\parskip`, e.g., a `\parskip` of height 0, might be interesting when register accuracy is important.

Comment: The default `\parskip`  (at least in standard classes as article)  is elastic (`0pt plus 1pt`) but usually not noticeable, whereas just `0pt` could avoid many opportunities to stylishly distribute the bottom space,  or worse, there are only a glue point in the middle and this leave a  eye-catching gap somewhere. Your mileage will vary a lot depending of the contents,  penalties, etc. The good news is that you can always change the settings in  preamble,  so once you have enough contents, you can easily  test the side effects of each setting.

Comment: @cabohah I didn't follow what you mean about vertical spaces used. Do you manually adapt the spaces around equations/figures/tables to ensure that the bottom lines line up?

Comment: @UlrichDiez I hadn't heard "register accuracy", does it refer to lines on the verso and recto pages being at the same height? That is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Have you got any suggestion on how to handle the situation of equations/figures/tables?

Comment: @Anna Register accuracy/register compliance - this is how google translate translates the German language term "Registerhaltigkeit" - means the matching of the baseline grid of all columns of text in the type-area - be the columns single columns or several columns placed on verso-pages and/or on recto-pages.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thank you, that's exactly what I meant. I'll give it a try when I've got most of the content written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment...

There are multiple issues. They can be solved, but the effort required to solve them may be more than you would wish to do.

As already noted, you can set various skips and glues to zero, or in some cases equal to the standard \baselineskip. In the case of ordinary text, particularly when single-column, that is helpful. But in the general case,
it may not be enough.

For example, if any of your text has characters (such as diacriticals) that extend higher than 0.7\baselineskip, or descend lower than 0.3\baselineskip, then TeX may automatically tweak inter-line spacing there. Word processors do the same thing, in their own context.

If you use minipage, or any of several other environments, then inter-line spacing may go slightly off-grid when you enter or leave the environment. This can be fixed.

Especially when you use equations, lists, tables, and figures, some things simply do not fit at a convenient size, unless you manually tweak things. Again, this can be fixed (but becomes more difficult if something splits pages).

Bottom line: The requested layout is not too hard for ordinary, running text, such as a novel. It is much harder for academic works, etc.

In the case of professionally typeset books, there is a lot of human intervention. Also, the editor is likely to be using page layout software with a GUI interface, so that objects can be visually moved around relative to other objects. Then the layout looks good, because it has been graphically designed, not by TeX command line.

Aside: Among popular books (not academic), I notice that the quality of digital typesetting seems to have decreased in recent years. My belief is that the books are quickly slapped together, because the market lifetime is short (and the primary customer base, libraries, do not care).

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful to know. If I were to give it a try, do you think I'd have to manually adjust each and every equation/figure/tables, or is there some technique to make sure that their height+spacing is an integer number of lines?

Comment: Also, I didn't realise that LaTeX adjusts the line spacing around diacritics. It seems  The Elements of Typographic Style does not.

Comment: @Anna I work only with text (not equations, figures, tables) and with raster images of specified dimensions. Also with limited font selection. With all these, it is indeed possible to fix the line grid, so that pages have the same integral number of lines. I have done it. BUT my own method is too restrictive for other TeX users. LaTeX does not always adjust the space around diacritics, only if "too much" for the line spacing, and most users will not encounter "too much." For manual adjustment, you can pad non-text elements with vertical space, so that following content is on-grid. Tedious.

Comment: Thank you! Knowing that I'd need manual adjustment for every element, I'll reconsider.